# bulk data transfer step of mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to migrate a database from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 to a local mysql database.Although the tool is able to migrate schema and table,it fails at the time of bulk data transfer.

my database name is university and my log show below message

```
13:42:11 [INF][copytable]: Connecting to MySQL server at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root
13:42:11 [INF][copytable]: Connection to MySQL opened

13:42:11 [INF][copytable]: Re-enabling triggers for schema 'university'

13:42:11 [INF][copytable]: No triggers found for 'university'
```

what should i do? please help me.

Comment: Contact the developers of the tool and inquire about what to do about this error.

Comment: Those message look to be informational rather than errors.

Comment: I don't see any errors in your log, can you provide full log file for more details?